# Is the term "site", as in "site-lisp", unique to Emacs?

Tags: site-lisp

I've inferred from the context in which it's used that "site" refers to a multi-user environment, as opposed to a particular user's section of that environment. But it's hard to find a formal explanation or origin for such a generic term.

Is it a holdover from an earlier time, unique to Emacs, or a widespread term that I was simply unaware of before diving into Emacs?

Comment: You can create several user accounts on the OS for your computer.  All these users' emacs will load `site-lisp`.  Here, your computer is a *site*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not specific to Emacs. And yes, it came from a time when a multi-user site (organization, school, company,...) installed Emacs for multiple-user use.

And yes, this is still the case sometimes. A company or other organization can well provide one or more company installations of Emacs, and provide company-specific customizations in `site-lisp`.

Furthermore, even if, say, a company has a giant farm of virtual GNU/Linux machines, and provides each of its developers with one such machine, it may well want to pre-install Emacs on each such machine or in a shared location, and it might provide company-specific code in `site-lisp` (also on each machine or in a shared location).